# fetch users' IP address through Firestore.instance.collection command?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating a customer satisfaction application in where I am looking to fetch users' IP address through the `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection` method. This in turn will allow me to narrow down the results of each set of feedback based on the user's IP, in order for a more coherent database.

This is the set of code under which I would like to add such command:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("feedback").doc()
.set({'type': 'bad chosen', 'timestamp': DateTime.now(),}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you need ip ? Don't you have some user id or something related to a user mapped in your firebase?

Comment: That's possible but it would be much simpler to have each user correspond with their unique IP, which would allow for better identification when going through the database :)